# Update All Row Hyperlinks To New Sheet

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, hyperlink

I have sheet with hyperlinks to cells within itself. I copied that sheet but now all hyperlinks point back to the "copied From" sheet instead of the newly created sheet.

All hyperlinks are on the header row - how do I update only the sheet they are referencing? My below code is not working.

```
Sub Macro6()
'
' Macro6 Macro
'
    Dim cell As Range
    With ActiveSheet
        For Each cell In .Range("B1:Z1")
        Dim old As String
        Dim old2 As String
        old = cell.Hyperlinks(1).SubAddress
        
            cell.Hyperlinks(1).SubAddress = Replace(cell.Hyperlinks(1).SubAddress, "'Sheet 1'", "'Sheet 3'")
            old2 = cell.Hyperlinks(1).SubAddress
       Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: What does "is not working mean"? Runtime error? Nothing happens? Have you debugged it?

Comment: @FunThomas nothing happens

Comment: @Excellerator Is the loop executed? Does _.SubAddress_ have the expected value (variables _old_ and _old2_)?

Comment: @Shrotter no, nothing happens

Comment: @Shrotter I’m losing sanity here, don’t see why it’s not working haha

Comment: @Excellerator please answer my questions (step wise execution of code, ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works for me - but only IF I rename the sheet to have a space between Sheet and the number ... that's not the default naming convention in Excel. if you make a new sheet - it's default will be Sheet# (no space).  Check that the new target has a space!

Also, in my test EVERY cell in the range I provided has a Hyperlink. If it is not every cell in the range - the quick fix is to put "On Error Resume Next" above the For Each line.   if you prefer not to use that --- you could loop through the hyperlinks

```
Sub Macro6()
'
' Macro6 Macro
'
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim myLink As Hyperlink
    
    With ActiveSheet
        For Each cell In .Range("I9:I12")
            Dim old As String
            Dim old2 As String
            
            For Each myLink In cell.Hyperlinks
            
                old = cell.Hyperlinks(1).SubAddress
                    
                    cell.Hyperlinks(1).SubAddress = Replace(cell.Hyperlinks(1).SubAddress, "'Sheet 1'", "'Sheet 3'")
                    old2 = cell.Hyperlinks(1).SubAddress
            
            Next
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I get this error: run-time error '9': Subscript out of range

Comment: Even though the sheet names match up exactly with the code

Comment: When debugging, this line is highlighted:
cell.Hyperlinks(1).SubAddress = Replace(cell.Hyperlinks(1).SubAddress, "'Site 1'", "'Site 3'")

Comment: revised response to address this issue